# Merge/Concat Issue

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have two `Dataframes` like the following:

DataFrame 1

```
ID  VALUE        DATE
1   google.com   12/28/2015
2   yahoo.com    12/28/2015
3   cnn.com      12/28/2015
4   facebook.com 12/28/2105
```

DataFrame 2

```
ID  COMMENT
1   Bad Stuff 
2   Good Stuff
3   Werid Stuff
4   Crazy Stuff
```

And the desired result will be here

```
ID   VALUE        DATE          COMMENT
1    google.com   12/28/2015    Bad Stuff
2    yahoo.com    12/28/2015    Good Stuff
3    cnn.com      12/28/2015    Weird Stuff
4    facebooo.com 12/28/2015    Crazy Stuff
```

Looks and seems so simple to me but I can't quite figure it out. I've read the Pandas documentation up and down and searched SOF for a while.

Here's what I have right now.

```
#Now, let's try to merge this data using Pandas
indicatorPanda = pd.read_csv('/tmp/i.csv')
commentPanda = pd.read_csv(open('/tmp/e.csv', 'rU'), encoding='utf-8')
mergedPanda = pd.concat([indicatorPanda, commentPanda], axis=1)
mergedPanda.to_csv('/tmp/output.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

I've come close but it looks like concating on Axis 1 still keeps that second 'ID' column at the end.

EDIT:
So I'm close now, I am using this:

```
    mergedPanda = indicatorPanda.merge(commentPanda, on='id', how='left')
```

But I am having an issue with duplicate rows with the same ID because of multiple lines in the Dataframe2

So now, here's what I want my end result to be:

DataFrame 1

```
ID  VALUE        DATE
1   google.com   12/28/2015
2   yahoo.com    12/28/2015
3   cnn.com      12/28/2015
4   facebook.com 12/28/2105
```

DataFrame 2

```
ID  COMMENT
1   Bad Stuff
1   Much Worse Stuff 
2   Good Stuff
3   Werid Stuff
4   Crazy Stuff
```

And the desired result will be here

```
ID   VALUE        DATE          COMMENT
1    google.com   12/28/2015    Bad Stuff | Much Worse Stuff
2    yahoo.com    12/28/2015    Good Stuff
3    cnn.com      12/28/2015    Weird Stuff
4    facebook.com 12/28/2015    Crazy Stuff
```

Is there a way to just concat the comments onto each other with some sort of character? I know we are out of the realm of regular SQL and Panda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `DataFrames` don't have `ID` set as index, so `.merge()` would work as [(see docs)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df3 = dataframe1.merge(dataframe2, on='ID', how='left)
```

Your `pd.concat()` merges on `index`, so it should work fine (`axis=1` means horizontal, as opposed to vertical combination) if you did `df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)` for both `DataFrame` before merging [(see docs)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html).

Comment: Thanks, that does "work" -- but I'm having an issue with duplicates. I want items to be added to the end of rows in DataFrame 1 no matter how many times they appear in DataFrame 2. Is this possible?

Comment: This sounds like you want to do a 'left' merge? See updated answer. You can specify to do `inner` (default), `right`, `left`, or `outer` join, following `sql` logic.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work:     mergedPanda = pd.merge(indicatorPanda, commentPanda, on='id', how='left')

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: I think you should be asking a new question.

Answer (score 2):

I think Merge would work well for your case.

```
 dataframe3 = pd.merge(dataframe1, dataframe2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```